# Surface Area of an Astroid

Tags: calculus, area

Compute the surface area of the surface generated by revolving the astroid with parametrization 
$$c(t) = \left(\cos^3 t,\sin^3t\right)$$ about the $x$-axis 
for $t\in[0,\pi/2]$.

I did not know how to go about answering this question and would really appreciate the help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner This is not a duplicate. The other question is about the area of part of an astroid in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This question is about the area of the surface obtained by revolving the planer astroid in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $S = \int^{\pi/2}_0 2\pi yds$ where $S$ is the surface area and $ds = \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt $. (The bounds on the integral come from your bounds).

First you should compute $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Then compute $ds$ and you could be able to solve it from there.

Answer (score 3):

We need to integrate $2\pi y\,ds$ over the appropriate interval, where 
$$ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}\,dt.$$
The differentiations are straightforward. The $ds$ simplifies to $3|\sin t\cos t|\,dt$, and from $0$ to $\pi/2$ there is no issue of signs. So we want
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 6\pi \sin^4 t\cos t\,dt.$$ 
Let $u=\sin t$, or just write down an antiderivative. The surface area is $\frac{6\pi}{5}$.

Comment: You are welcome. I have left some algebra for you to do. Please indicate if you run into difficulties.

Comment: I finished the algebra and the rest of the equation! Thank you again for the help.